# innerHTML works fine in Firefox whereas when I tried the same in Chrome it is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to get the tooltip text using JavaScriptExecutor. The code works fine in Firefox whereas the same code is not working in Chrome.

The Scenario is:
When I select an invalid file type in the upload file field I will be getting validation message as tooltip message. To get the tooltip message I am using following code

`String invalidFileTypeMessag = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", tooltipWebElement);`

Exactly the same code works in Firefox and not in Chrome.

Comment: why are you using `JavascriptExecutor` and not `GetAttribute` method ?

Comment: Why not use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: @Madhan using textContent is giving me following error "no such element: Unable to locate element". My code works perfectly fine with Firefox but it is creating this issue with Chrome.

Comment: @GaurangShah as I am trying to retrieve the text from hidden div tag. The tag will be visible only if we mouseover on a specific field.

Comment: @SujaiKrishna that's the issue then. do exactly as you will do it manually. first do the mousever event and then try to get the element attribute. I am sure will work for most of the browsers.

Comment: Finally, found a solution for my question. @GaurangShah thanks for the heads up on performing Mouseover before retrieving the text.

Comment: I still advice on using Webdriver API rather than Javascript, as webdriver is native events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing the following code help fixing my issue.

```
 try 
     {
         String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover',true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
         ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript,uploadFileInputFieldWebElement);
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         invalidLicenseFileTypeMessag = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;",tooltipWebElement);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        exception message;

    }
```